# "cannot execute script" error in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I frequently get the following error when attempting to execute simple statements against a remote instance of SQL Server 2005.  I click execute, the window hangs for several seconds, then I get the error.  I click OK, click Execute again, and it runs fine.  This happens frequently enough to be very annoying.

Last week I worked exclusively against a local instance and didn't have this problem once.  I was also not on the corporate domain all week (business trip).

My machine is Vista.

What's causing this issue?  How do I resolve?

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Cannot execute script.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Access to the path 'C:\Users\[chloraphil]\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp873B.tmp' is denied. (mscorlib)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Comment: Problem went away when my hard drive died :)

Comment: I get this error about 50% of the time on one of my PCs (connecting to a local server). In ProcMon I can see that the failing executions are all associated with an operation `SetDispositionInformationFile` which gives the result `CANNOT DELETE`. No other processes such as AV seem to be locking the file so not sure of the reason for this. I do have SSMS Tools Pack installed and wonder whether the query logging functionality might be causing this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem went away when my hard drive died :)

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting all the files in the temp folder in the error message. Ignore errors on files that are open by other processes. I had over 3 GB of files there.

Answer (score 0):

I double-clicked on the .sql script when it was inside a zip file, it opened in SQL Server Management Studio - but when I tried to execute it - it gave me this error.

Move/Unzip the .sql script outside of the archive and it will run.